# How to calculate latlong difference from last 15 min ago and last 1 min ago without using correlation subqueries

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, subquery

### Problem

I would like to find logs that are active and do not hit a distance quota of 12.5km, comparing from last 15 min ago and latest (within last 1 min ago)

### Sample data

```
select version();
```

| version() |
| --- |
| 5.7.39 |

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `consignment` (
  `consignment_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `stop_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `truck_truck_id` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`consignment_id`),
  KEY `consignment_truck_truck_id_index` (`truck_truck_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `consignment`
--

INSERT INTO `consignment` (`consignment_id`, `start_time`, `stop_time`, `truck_truck_id`) VALUES
(1, NULL, NULL, 'DEF699'),
(2, NULL, NULL, 'LOL999'),
(11, '2022-11-28 08:36:47', NULL, 'ABC123');
```

> ```
> Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gps_log` (
  `gps_log_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lat` double NOT NULL,
  `long` double NOT NULL,
  `log_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `consignment_consignment_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gps_log_id`),
  KEY `gps_log_consignment_consignment_id_index` (`consignment_consignment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `gps_log` (`gps_log_id`, `lat`, `long`, `log_time`, `consignment_consignment_id`) VALUES
(1, 36.47579591525347, -86.677500994023, '2022-11-28 08:11:51', 1),
(2, 36.47053036255657, -86.6787666877346, '2022-11-28 08:12:56', 2),
(3, 36.475240655695934, -86.71250224047003, '2022-11-28 08:38:29', 11),
(4, 36.475240655695934, -86.71250224047003, '2022-11-28 08:49:19', 11),
(5, 36.475240655695934, -86.71250224047003, '2022-11-28 08:53:22', 11),
(6, 36.475240655695934, -86.71250224047003, '2022-11-28 09:38:55', 11),
(7, 36.475240655695934, -86.71250224047003, '2022-11-28 09:38:55', 1),
(8, 36.475240655695934, -86.71250224047003, '2022-11-28 09:53:55', 1);

ALTER TABLE `gps_log`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `gps_log_consignment_consignment_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`consignment_consignment_id`) REFERENCES `consignment` (`consignment_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

> ```
> Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

> ```
> Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM `gps_log`
```

| gps_log_id | lat | long | log_time | consignment_consignment_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 36.47579591525347 | -86.677500994023 | 2022-11-28 08:11:51 | 1 |
| 2 | 36.47053036255657 | -86.6787666877346 | 2022-11-28 08:12:56 | 2 |
| 3 | 36.475240655695934 | -86.71250224047003 | 2022-11-28 08:38:29 | 11 |
| 4 | 36.475240655695934 | -86.71250224047003 | 2022-11-28 08:49:19 | 11 |
| 5 | 36.475240655695934 | -86.71250224047003 | 2022-11-28 08:53:22 | 11 |
| 6 | 36.475240655695934 | -86.71250224047003 | 2022-11-28 09:38:55 | 11 |
| 7 | 36.475240655695934 | -86.71250224047003 | 2022-11-28 09:38:55 | 1 |
| 8 | 36.475240655695934 | -86.71250224047003 | 2022-11-28 09:53:55 | 1 |

```
SELECT * FROM `consignment`
```

| consignment_id | start_time | stop_time | truck_truck_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | *null* | DEF699 |
| 2 | *null* | *null* | LOL999 |
| 11 | 2022-11-28 08:36:47 | *null* | ABC123 |

### Currently stuck at...

```
-- My attempt

SELECT `gps_log`.*, ST_Distance_Sphere( POINT (36.475240655695934, -86.71250224047003), -- IDK how to get data here: gps_log_id: 3
                              POINT(gps_log.`long`, gps_log.`lat`)) 
          AS `distance_in_km` 
FROM `gps_log`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `tmp`.* 
    FROM `gps_log` as `tmp`
    WHERE `tmp`.`consignment_consignment_id` IN (
                                SELECT c.`consignment_id` 
                                FROM `consignment` as c
                                WHERE c.`start_time` IS NOT NULL
                                AND c.`stop_time` IS NULL
                                ) 
    AND `tmp`.`log_time` > NOW() - INTERVAL 36000 MINUTE -- Compare data from 15 min ago and data from 1 min ago... we simulate 3600
    ORDER BY `gps_log_id` DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS table_2
ON `gps_log`.`gps_log_id` = `table_2`.`gps_log_id`
```

| gps_log_id | lat | long | log_time | consignment_consignment_id | distance_in_km |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 36.475240655695934 | -86.71250224047003 | 2022-11-28 09:38:55 | 11 | 14257834.99373771 |

### Desired output

Get logs have a dist < 12.5km from 15 min ago:

| gps_log_id | lat | long | log_time | consignment_consignment_id | distance_in_km |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 36.475240655695934 | -86.71250224047003 | 2022-11-28 09:38:55 | 11 | 0 |
| 8 | 36.475240655695934 | -86.71250224047003 | 2022-11-28 09:53:55 | 1 | 0 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U7YgaS-H)

### Edit

For those with a similar problem, but seeking a simpler solution, the best solution is to create a `speed` field in table. However, due to the limitations of the project manager/client, I am required to calculate distance instead.

Comment: *Expected output* ??? Why `consignment_id` is included into the output? it does not match ```WHERE `start_time` IS NOT NULL AND `stop_time` IS NULL```. PS. https://dbfiddle.uk/05a42n4V

Comment: @Akina Sorry, I phrase it wrongly. I meant to say desired output

Comment: `IN trucks_on_duty` looks like a syntax error??

Comment: @RickJames yes, it's a fake sql that i am trying to achieve

Comment: Please use valid syntax (with fake numbers/dates/strings), else we don't know whether to focus on syntax errors versus logic errors versus something else.

Comment: @RickJames Tks, I have updated the description

Comment: Now I am lost on the criteria.  What controls "active"?  Which of the sample rows are within the desired distance?  Is the time range "between 15 min ago and 1 min ago?  Which sample rows match that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unclear on the specifics, but I am pretty sure it takes two steps:

1. Find the rows that match the "active", "distance quota", and "15 to 1 minute ago".  See the Comment where I asked for specifics.
2. Find the latest of each.  This involves a "groupwise max" algorithm; see the tag I added.

Then put the two pieces together.  MySQL 8.0 has CTEs, which would make it easier.  But, since you are on 5.7, it gets messier

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t
    SELECT ... ((step 1));
```

Then apply the group-wise max to `t`.

If you have thousands of rows, optimization will be a problem.  This is because the distance calc is slow.  We can discuss that after you get the code working [slowly] with the groupwise-max.

If you will have millions of rows and the resolution needed is only enough to distinguish two trucks, see this for picking something less bulky than `DOUBLE` (8 bytes each) for lat and lng:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng#representation_choices